# how to set image using css ( background-image property)?

Tags: css, web, google-web-designer

I need to know how to set background image in CSS using background-image property.

The image cannot show in the browser. i don not know what is the reason but my file image path is from the desktop but i should use ../ use to set but it nothing will appear .Can anyone know this please help to set this problem

Comment: you are trying to show it on a local website or on the web ? :) can you show use the code you are using ?

Comment: css class as "copy" and the css is .copy{
    background-image: url("../sample/wp-content/uploads/gif/banner_12.png") right center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your code is as follows

```
.copy{ background-image: url("../sample/wp-content/uploads/gif/banner_12.png") right center no-repeat; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; 

}
```

In your `background-image` declaration you should include ONLY the image url. Instead you include `right center` which is the `background-position` and `no-repeat` which is `background-repeat`

Either you write all the styles separately like so

```
.copy{
    background-image :url("../sample/wp-content/uploads/gif/banner_12.png")
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

*optionally include background-attachment ( scroll is default) and background-color ( transparent is default )*

Either you write them in a single declaration like so

```
.copy {
    background:url("../sample/wp-content/uploads/gif/banner_12.png") no-repeat right center / cover 
}
```